# bash cp -r except for a specific file type

Tags: bash, scripting, cp

I have a bash script that contains:

```
for i in $(stuff);
do other-stuff; cp -r $i $p;
done
```

but I don't have read permissions to a specific log dump file type, let's call it .txt

Currently I get:
cp: cannot open `file.txt' for reading: Permission denied

Without changing any permissions, is there an easy way to copy everything except those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cp` doesn't hang when it generates that message. It just skips the file. Add in verbose (`cp -vr $i $p`) and you'll see that its either busy copying other files, or alternatively something else in your script is hanging.

`cp` doesn't really have a way to exclude files its recursing over. If you want that, you'll have to switch to something more featureful, like `tar` (possibly with `find`) or `rsync`.

Also, you should really quote your arguments, just in case they contain spaces: `cp -r "$i" "$p"`

Comment: good call. it wasn't hanging, just copying over a lot more files than originally anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

Test if the file is readable by the current user with `if [ -r "$i" ]`:

```
for i in $(stuff);
    if [ -r "$i" ]; do
        cp -r $i $p
    fi
done
```

More info here: [File test operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html)

> Flag Returns true if...
>   `-r`
> file has read permission (for the user running the test)
>
> `-w`
> file has write permission (for the user running the test)
>
> `-x`
> file has execute permission (for the user running the test)

Comment: assume $(stuff) is a \n delimited list of paths

Comment: @mbarrows: I hope you know that `for i in FOO` splits FOO on words, as defined by `$IFS`, not on lines. Unless you change IFS, of course. You probably want to read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ — it's the first question.

Answer (score 0):

```
do other-stuff; $i =~ "*.txt" || cp -r $i $p;
```

You may need grouping here; I didn't check the operator precedences and I can't keep them all in my head. But `~=` does a regex. If it succeeds the copy will be skipped.